# None of my CSS or JavaScript is modifying the <div> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mHaLm/) is the problem that I am experiencing illustrated in a JSFiddle. I am making a loading screen that will slide up after a few seconds using jQuery. I am fairly new at jQuery, but not with HTML, JavaScript, or CSS. As with my usual questions, I suspect that this has an extremely obvious answer that I have overlooked. My question is: **Why is the div not being affected by anything?** Apparently I need links to jsfiddle.net to be accompanied by code...

HTML:

```
<div id="loader" style="height:0;width:0;">
<strong style="color:white">Loading...</strong>
</div>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();
document.getElementById("loader").style.height = height + "px";
document.getElementById("loader").style.width = width + "px";
```

CSS:

```
#loader {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I would appreciate any help that can be given.

**Edit**: Since I lack reputation to answer my own problem with 8 hours of posting, this will have to do. [Meredith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2125913/meredith) provided me with a solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mHaLm/3/). Thank you.

**Edit 2**: After some research, I realized that I was attempting to do all of that before the page had fully loaded. When I tried Meredith's method, it didn't work. I changed my JavaScript/jQuery to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var width = $(window).width();
  var height = $(window).height();
  document.getElementById("loader").style.height = height + "px";
  document.getElementById("loader").style.width = width + "px";
});
```

And everything worked fine.

Comment: It's working fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/mHaLm/3/

Comment: not really sure what you actually want to achieve? slide up the div after few second? change the background?

Comment: You mean you want to change the back ground color?

Comment: I have no idea what you did different, Meredith, but it now works fine as well... Thank you?

Comment: Sounds like he's trying to make the div the size of the window, which his code does. I added a background color to make it visible.

Comment: @jack_dalton15 All I did was add a background color to #loader to show that it was resizing

Comment: Se0ng11 my plan was to slide it up. It is all good now, Meredith got my back :P.

Comment: mark @Meredith  answer as answer if that did help you

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually just changes the height and width of the div (successfully) but does nothing in order to slide it up after some period of time. I would suggest using jQuery's slideUp. Add this after your javascript:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#loader").slideUp()
}, 1000)
```

$("#loader") is the jQuery's way of accessing the div with "loader" id. This is just an example of how to slide the div up after some predefined time. You would probably like to do it after your loading procedure finishes.

Comment: My question was just about making the `<div>` be affected by my CSS and other things, rather than the sliding up. I can slide it up just fine, thank you ;).